# Mongodb C# driver - how to upsert in nested array

Tags: c#, mongodb, filter, bulkinsert, upsert

I have an application with the following mongodb document structure:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("123456789"),
  "DateStamp" : ISODate("2021-11-21T00:00:00.000Z"),
  "Codes" : [ 
  {
    "Code" : "1000",
    "Ident" : "ABC"
  }, 
  {
    "Code" : "1001",
    "Ident" : "DEF"
  },
  {
    "Code" : "1002",
    "Ident" : null
  }
  ]
}
```

For each day such a document is created, with several codes stored in the nested array.
The application receives requests to upsert the codes for the actual day. The upsert rules are as following:

if the code is already existing for the day and the ident is not null → do nothing
if the code is already existing for the day and the ident is null → update the ident
if the code is not existing → insert new code+ident
Here is a sample application code:

```
public class MyDoc
{
public List<CodeInfo> Codes { get; set; }

[BsonElement("DateStamp")]
[BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Utc)]
public DateTime DateStamp { get; set; }
}

public class CodeInfo
{
public string Code { get; set; }
public string Ident { get; set; }
}      
   
Main()
{
...
  var actUtcDt = DateTime.UtcNow;
  var dateStr = actUtcDt.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
  var dayParsed = DateTime.ParseExact(dateStr, "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
  var dayParsedUtc = dayParsed.ToUniversalTime();

  var newCodes = new List<CodeInfo>
           {
          new CodeInfo { Code = "1000", Ident = "ABC2" },
          new CodeInfo { Code = "1002", Ident = "EFGH" },
          new CodeInfo { Code = "1003", Ident = "MNOP" }
           };

  var myNewDoc = new MyDoc { DateStamp = dayParsedUtc, Codes = newCodes };

  UpsertMyDoc(myNewDoc);
  ...
}

void UpsertMyDoc(MyDoc myDoc)
{
  IMongoCollection<MyDoc> mongoCollection = ...;
  var filterMyDocBuilder = Builders<MyDoc>.Filter;
  var updateMyDocBuilder = Builders<MyDoc>.Update;

  var dtUtc = myDoc.DateStamp;

  var filterDate = filterMyDocBuilder.Eq(x => x.DateStamp, dtUtc);

  // only set on insert
  var updateDef = updateMyDocBuilder
      .SetOnInsert(p => p.DateStamp, dtUtc)
      .SetOnInsert(p => p.Codes, myDoc.Codes)
  ;
  var options = new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true };

  var updRes = await mongoCollection.UpdateOneAsync(filterDate, updateDef, options);
  // check if a document for the day is already existing
  var dayAvailable = updRes.IsAcknowledged && updRes.MatchedCount == 1 && updRes.UpsertedId == null;

  if (dayAvailable)
  {
      var filterCodeInfoBuilder = Builders<CcodeInfo>.Filter;

      // update codes with null ident
      var updateNullIdentModels = myDoc.Codes.Select(x =>
      {
          var codeFilter = filterCodeInfoBuilder.Eq(p => p.Code, x.Barcode);
          var isNullIdentFilter = filterCodeInfoBuilder.Eq(p => p.Ident, null);
          var combinedFilters = filterCodeInfoBuilder.And(codeFilter, isNullIdentFilter);

          var filterDefinition = filterDate &
                                 filterMyDocBuilder.ElemMatch(day => day.Codes, combinedFilters);
          var codeInfoUpdate = updateMyDocBuilder.Set(c => c.Codes[-1].Ident, x.Ident);

          return new UpdateOneModel<MyDoc>(filterDefinition, codeInfoUpdate) { IsUpsert = false };
      }).ToList();

      // insert new codes, only if not already existing
      var insertNewCodeModels = myDoc.Codes.Select(x =>
      {
        ....???
      }).ToList();

      var bulkOps = new List<WriteModel<MyDoc>>();
      bulkOps.AddRange(updateNullIdentModels);
      bulkOps.AddRange(insertNewCodeModels);

      BulkWriteResult bulkWrRes = await mongoCollection.BulkWriteAsync(bulkOps);
  }
}
```

For the newCodes list it is expected that the code "1000" is ignored, the code "1002" updates the ident and the code "1003" is inserted. The “upserted” document should now look like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("123456789"),
  "DateStamp" : ISODate("2021-11-21T00:00:00.000Z"),
  "Codes" : [ 
  {
    "Code" : "1000",
    "Ident" : "ABC"
  }, 
  {
    "Code" : "1001",
    "Ident" : "DEF"
  },
  {
    "Code" : "1002",
    "Ident" : "EFGH"
  },
  {
    "Code" : "1003",
    "Ident" : "MNOP"
  }
]
}
```

How can this be achieved for the mongodb above document structure, in c# ? I cannot figure out how to insert in the nested array only the codes which are not already existing.